# How to write query for this given result?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, rdbms

Table "*question*":

| q_id | s_id question |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 |

Table "*result*":

| id | q_id | s_id | answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 1 | yes |
| 2 | 9 | 1 | no |
| 3 | 10 | 1 | yes |
| 4 | 8 | 1 | no |
| 5 | 9 | 1 | yes |
| 6 | 10 | 1 | yes |

I want the result to look like this how can I do this can anyone help me or suggest what I can do ??

- have to take s_id from user as input

| question | yes | no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| like coffee?? | 1 | 1 |
| like water?? | 1 | 1 |
| like tea?? | 2 | 0 |

Comment: Use conditional aggregation. Or corelated subqueries.

Comment: This is a simple *Pivot* - please show us what you have tried so far and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future it would help if you make a reproducible example using something like https://dbfiddle.uk/.

If you want to pivot like this, you will need to use `GROUP BY` and some aggregation. I would include s_id and q_id in your result as well, just in case you would like more than one student's result, of if there are identical questions with different q_id. I commented them out in this example:

```
SELECT 
  -- question.s_id, 
  -- question.q_id,
  question.question, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN result.answer = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS yes,
  SUM(CASE WHEN result.answer = 'no' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS no
FROM question 
JOIN result
ON  question.s_id = result.s_id
AND question.q_id = result.q_id
WHERE question.s_id = 1 -- your input
GROUP BY 
  -- question.s_id, 
  -- question.q_id,
  question.question
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b4b12dd1ff4af30145a249cc3dc5d7a6)*

Comment: thankyou so much I have learnt a lot from your answer